# Nested SQL query with system timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I am creating a web-application and backend DB for a carsharing venture. I want to ensure that only search results for cars that are not reserved as of the current time are shown. I've typed up a query (below) but I am unsure if it is correct. I am using two relations, Reservations and Cars.

```
Reservations(R_No, M_ID, VIN, A_Code, start_time, end_time)
Cars(VIN, make, model, year, P_address, r_fee)
```

Is this a valid query? If not, what would make it valid?

```
$sql = "SELECT make, model, year, P_address, r_fee, VIN 
                    FROM `Cars`, `Reservations`
                    WHERE (
                            (make LIKE %'$search'% ) or
                            (model LIKE %'$search'%) or
                            (year LIKE %'$search'%) or
                            (P_address LIKE %'$search'%) or
                            (r_fee LIKE %'$search'%) and
            (Cars.VIN != Reservations.VIN)
        AND (
            SELECT start_time, end_time
            FROM   Reservations
            WHERE  end_time <= SYSDATETIME() <= start_time));"
```

Comment: If a certain car does not match to anything in the reservation table, then how can it possibly have a reservation?

Comment: `Is this a valid query` ... it won't run, if you've tried it, so no, it isn't valid.

Comment: First off, instead of %'$search'%, it would be '%$search%'. Second, your query is suseptable to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Also, use proper table joins, with the where reserved for limiting the overall results. Use BETWEEN for the date part. Lastly, show your table schemas. If end_time and start_time are timestamps vs. dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be modified to use a parameterized query, and would be subject to SQL injection.

```
$sql = "SELECT c.`make`, c.`model`, c.`year`, c.`P_address`, c.`r_fee`, c.`VIN`
    FROM `Cars` c
    LEFT JOIN `Reservations` r
    ON c.`VIN` = r.`VIN` AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEN r.`end_time` AND r.`start_time`
    WHERE (
            (c.`make` LIKE '%$search%' ) or
            (c.`model` LIKE '%$search%') or
            (c.`year` LIKE '%$search%') or
            (c.`P_address` LIKE '%$search%') or
            (c.`r_fee` LIKE '%$search%')
        )
        AND r.`id` IS NULL;";
```

This will return a list of cars that do not have a reservation currently. However, you probably really want to extend the start and end time
period so you don't get cars that have a reservation that starts very soon.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Sloan!